# The appearance of windows change when i connect the second monitor

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

I recently installed ubuntu and I found this problem.
I have a Nvidia 630M I think may be causing the problem

When I connect my second monitor, change the look to a style windows 1998. Horrible!

I leave a video.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4EgQOB1VhcM

Any solution?

Thanks -.

Comment: Well, after watching your video I can see that the only window that has "changed the look to a style windows 1998" is the Google Chrome/Chromium Browser. Did you already try disabling the "Use System Titlebar and borders" option in chrome/chromium? The rest of the windows looks like a normal Unity with Ambiance theme. The video is too dark, thus I can't see such a major difference. Sorry. Try disabling system titlebar and borders in the web browser. If you are using a composition/windows decorator such as Emerald or Compiz you may need to restart it after plugging your second monitor in.

Comment: Ok, after watching your video with more detail I can see that you mean the context menu. You may wish to reword your question in order to include this information so that you can receive the best support. Thank you.